# How do I add a drop down menu using my current CSS?

Tags: html, css

I understand the basics of making a drop down menu using my current HTML but don't understand how I can do the same with my current CSS. I am also pretty new to HTML and CSS so much help would be appreciated thanks!
Here is my HTML coding:

```css
/*The overflow:hidden hides the scroller that appears on page*/
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

html {
 background: url('http://pre15.deviantart.net/5686/th/pre/i/2016/338/6/2/living_tree_by_tacosauceninja-daqj4zz.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
 background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

/* The code below is what makes the bar invisible*/
#navdiv{
 opacity: 0.7;
 filter: (opacity=70);
}

#navdiv ul {
 width:100%;
 height: 80px;
 background:#648DA0;
 line-height:80px;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
}

#navdiv ul a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}


/*The padding left and right allows you to choose the spacing between each page on your navigation bar*/
#navdiv ul li {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding-left: 50px;
 padding-right: 50px;
 display: inline-block;
 float: center;
}

#navdiv ul li:hover{
 background: #8FB0BF;
 text-align: center;
 transition:all 0.40s;
 
}

#navdiv h1{
 width: 300px;
 float:center;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Homepage</title>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

 <body>
 
  <div id="Maindiv">
   <div id="navdiv">
     <h1> Hello World... </h1>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="relax.html" class="btn-default"> Relax </a></li>
     <li><a href="motivation.html" class="btn-default"> Motivation </a></li>
     <li><a href="homepage.html" class="btn-default">HomePage</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
     <li><a href="healing.html" class="btn-default"> Healing </a></li>
    </ul>
    
   </div>
  </div>
 
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you know to nest a UL in the LI to make a drop down menu?

What you'll need to do in your CSS is set `display:none` to the submenu and then change it to `display:block` when the user hovers over the corresponding li.

I have added a basic snippet as an idea to show you as simple as possible.

```css
ul { 
  list-style-type: none;
}

/* Hide the submenu */
ul.submenu {
  display: none;
}

/* Show the submenu when hovering over the li */
li.dropdown:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Link</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

One thing I would change in your HTML though is the use of ID's. Just give everything a class name and then you've more control.

Comment: Thanks! Your reply helps a lot.